# Getting the table name to select on from the user

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

My problem is I have a SELECT query but the table to select the data from needs to be specified by the user, from an HTML file. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

I am querying a postgres database and the SQL queries are in a python file.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable `table_name` and **verify it contains only characters allowed in a table name**. Then put it into the SQL query:

```
sql = "SELECT ... FROM {} WHERE ...".format(table_name) # replace ... with real sql
```

If you don't verify it and the user sends something nasty, [you run into risk](http://xkcd.com/327/).